# Apache2: Internal Server Error with log "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500

Tags: php, apache, internal

My Server is Apache2 on Ubuntu. I did a new server setup. Whenever i am hitting IP address in browser i am getting:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

My Server log file:

```
[25/Jul/2016:05:53:43 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 708 "http://13x.xx.xx.xx/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

I do not have any favicon link/url in my html. Also it is not going to html page (as i have traced). Even it is not going to my project /index.php file.

If i ping on my local computer command prompt is says:

```
Reply from 13x.xx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL:56
Reply from 13x.xx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL:56
Reply from 13x.xx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL:56
Reply from 13x.xx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL:56
Packets: Sent=4 received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
```

Can suggest where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: "Can suggest where i am doing wrong ?" — You appear to be looking at the access log instead of the error log.

Comment: "I do not have any favicon link/url in my html." — Doesn't matter. Browsers will guess the URL.

Comment: "Also it is not going to html page" — Well no. You said it was going to a 500 error.

Comment: "If i ping" — Then it tells you that you can talk to your server, which you already knew because if you couldn't talk to it then it couldn't send you a 500 Internal Error response.

Comment: Error Log: .htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://13x.xx.xx.xx/

Comment: Chrome likes to automatically request a favicon, even if there is none in the html source code. The error doesn' even lay there. Check the webserver/PHP errorlog why it throws a 500 when you try to access the website.

Answer (score 3):

> Error Log: .htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

So you have an `.htaccess` file which is configuring your server to rewrite some URLs, but the module needed to do that hasn't been loaded.

Either:

- Edit the `.htaccess` file so it doesn't do that *or*
- [Change the server configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_so.html) to load [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)